# Using Stack<> to filter HTML documents

Tags: javascript, c#, html, function, youtube

I'm creating a **software** which is basically a "Kid Friendly" video streaming software. My issue right now is how to **filter** out "bad" content on a YouTube page. It would have to **read the HTML**, and replace **bad** content with XXX.

To get the HTML I use the **webbrowser object**, which I called **videoStreamer**.

```
string HTML = videoStreamer.DocumentText;
```

Then, I could either write the HTML to a text file, or modify it directly. Since it is a string, all the string functions are enabled.

My question is how to use a **stack** to filter through this HTML, or if using a stack is not the best way. What is?

Comment: I'm not sure a stack will work for you, since some HTML elements (such as `<p>`) are [not guaranteed to have a corresponding end element](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp).  Perhaps  the [Microsoft HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) could be used?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! I'll see what I can do :D